# Python: Pandas, Text File to DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a text file which is of the form: [image: txt.file]

I want to create a dataframe from this, using separated by the whitespace, as columns, and use the letters at the top as column names, then export the dataframe to excel. This is the code I have constructed so far:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('testrun.txt', delim_whitespace=True, header = None, names = ["n", "p", "d", "f", "g"])

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df.to_excel(r'C:\Users\"my_name"\Desktop\spdsht.xlsx')
```

So far this code sucks the n, p, d, f, g into the data frame as just another row. Is there anyway I can omit this first row, and have pandas append it as the column names? As you can see, I already put the column names in manually, but that doesn't get rid of the n, p, d, f, g within the first row.

Comment: Did you try: `data = pd.read_csv('testrun.txt', delim_whitespace=True)`?

Comment: Oh wow, It works now. I didn't think it could do that! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: try skiprows = 1 so should skip first row

Comment: your `header=None` parameter was telling `read_csv` to include that first row as a row.  without it, as @MaxU has pointed out, you get what you want.