# How to get Python pandas DataFrame from string written by print()?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, csv, pandas

THIS is an updated version of the question providing a handy function

**`pd_read_printed(str_printed_df)`**

designed to create a pandas DataFrame out of the string written previously using print(some_pandas_DataFrame) :

> ```
> def pd_read_printed(str_printed_df):
>     global pd, StringIO
>     try: x = pd
>     except: import pandas as pd
>     try: x = StringIO
>     except: from pandas.compat import StringIO
>     return pd.read_csv(StringIO(str_printed_df), delim_whitespace=True)
> ```

I put it together for own use after I have got here the answers to the following question:

I see in Internet often the content of a pandas DataFrame in its printed version like for example::

```
df1_as_string = """
 Sp   Mt   Value  count
4  MM2  S4   bg     10
5  MM2  S4   dgd    1
6  MM4  S2   rd     2
7  MM4  S2   cb     8
8  MM4  S2   uyi    8 
"""
```

The question is: How to obtain a variable holding the DataFrame from a string  variable in a style like:

```
df1 = pandas.someToMeUnknownPandasFunction(df1_as_string)
```

?

NOW let's use the provided function to create a DataFrame from `df1_as_string`:

```
df1 = pd_read_printed(df1_as_string)
```

and check if it worked as expected:

```
print(df1)
```

gives:

```
    Sp  Mt Value  count
4  MM2  S4    bg     10
5  MM2  S4   dgd      1
6  MM4  S2    rd      2
7  MM4  S2    cb      8
8  MM4  S2   uyi      8
```

Comment: May be you are looking for `pandas.read_clipboard()`?

Comment: I asked the same question not so long ago:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43172452/convert-text-table-to-pandas-dataframe

Comment: @beniev yes ... a SIMILAR question, but you have overseen that it was already at that time answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40117799/python-pandas-text-file-to-dataframe .

Comment: ok... so if you didn't oversee it why did you ask this question...?

Comment: @beniev I wanted an answer for output of `print()`, but I found only some for text-tables and didn't recognize that it will be the same answer. NOW after I have got an answer I have realized that I had it found already before, but couldn't see it is one I could use for my purpose ... By the way: I am a bit dissapointed that there is no read_print() function in pandas as I am not (yet) familiar with csv ...

Comment: I don't think you should edit your question with an answer after it's been answered...it goes against the whole Q&A philosophy. Questions are for questions, answers are for answers.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use [`read_clipboard`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_clipboard.html).

```
df = pd.read_clipboard()
```

Or [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) with separator one or more `whitespace`s - `sep='\s+'` or `delim_whitespace=True`:

```
from pandas.compat import StringIO

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(df1_as_string), sep="\s+")
```

```
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(df1_as_string), delim_whitespace=True)
```

---

```
print (df)
    Sp  Mt Value  count
4  MM2  S4    bg     10
5  MM2  S4   dgd      1
6  MM4  S2    rd      2
7  MM4  S2    cb      8
8  MM4  S2   uyi      8
```

Comment: Glad can help you! Nice day!

Comment: `read_clipboard()` - Nice *tip* to  work with examples from questions on SO

Answer (score 6):

Two methods

***option 1***
[**`pd.read_clipboard`**](http://pandas.read_clipboard%20%E2%80%94%20pandas%200.19.2%20documentation)

This is my goto method for simply formatted dataframes.  I copy the dataframe text and follow it up with `df = pd.read_clipboard()`

***option 2***
[**`StringIO`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO) + [**`pd.read_csv`**](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjjn8PJ0rrTAhUl44MKHVGQAgQQFggjMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpandas.pydata.org%2Fpandas-docs%2Fstable%2Fgenerated%2Fpandas.read_csv.html&usg=AFQjCNE1cTwGgwS3WFrM8PRoP9YzTbLAGA&sig2=ELvjSXwxBy1Cnk0Z9CZ0Rg)

For dataframes that have more complicated structure, I may need some of the options in `read_csv` so I might set it up this way.  Keep in mind that for the dataframe you provided, I'd almost never do it this way because it's slower for me to get at a dataframe.

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

df1_as_string = """
 Sp   Mt   Value  count
4  MM2  S4   bg     10
5  MM2  S4   dgd    1
6  MM4  S2   rd     2
7  MM4  S2   cb     8
8  MM4  S2   uyi    8 
"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(df1_as_string), delim_whitespace=True)
```

In either case, I end up with:

```
print(df)

    Sp  Mt Value  count
4  MM2  S4    bg     10
5  MM2  S4   dgd      1
6  MM4  S2    rd      2
7  MM4  S2    cb      8
8  MM4  S2   uyi      8
```